# PHP AJAX JQuery xmlhttp request Get method sends always 1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send a Get method value for my AJAX Jquery PhP request. Before the value be sent to the PHP file it's value was the one i am expecting but by the time the php file reads the GET value it becomes 1 all the time no matter what i pick in my combo box.

PHP File (UI)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <?php include ('includes/header.php'); ?>


    <navigation>
    <div id="nav-bar">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li role="p_resentation"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li role="p_resentation" class="active"><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
            <li role="p_resentation"><a href="manufacturing.php">Manufacturing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</navigation>
<br />

   <div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="col-sm-8" id="row1-sm8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="content-heading">


                <select name="users" onchange="getvalue(this.value)" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    <option value="">Select a field:</option>
                    <option value="1">Product Name</option>
                    <option value="2">SO #</option>
                    <option value="3">Assembly Name</option>
                    <option value="4">Sales Person</option>
                    <option value="5">Customer Name</option>
                    <option value="6">PO / Remarks</option>
                    <option value="7">SO Status</option>
                    <option value="8">Delivery Status</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div>
                <table class="table">
                    <div class="panel-body" id="output">

                    </div>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="row1-sm4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="login-heading">Filters</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <br/>
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Field</td>
                                <td>Value</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include ('includes/footer.php'); ?>

<script>
function getvalue(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        alert(str);
        xmlhttp.open("GET","_db/getvalue.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
       }
}
</script>
```

Here is my Receiver PHP file that will process the data

```
<html>
<body>
    <table class="table">
<?php
    include('../includes/links/js.php');
    include('../includes/links/css.php');
    include('/connection/connect.php');
    $val = intval($_GET['q']);
    $field = '';
    $group = '';

    if ($val = 1) {
        $field = "(SELECT pp1.name_template FROM product_product pp1 WHERE boml.product_id = pp1.id) as BOML";
        $group = "BOML";
    } elseif ($val = 2) {
        $field = "so.name as SO";
        $group = "SO";
    } elseif ($val = 3) {
        $field = "sol.name as assembly";
        $group = "assembly";
    } elseif ($val = 4) {
        $field = "split_part(u.login, '@', 1) as sales_person";
        $group = "sales_person";
    } elseif ($val = 5) {
        $field = "c.display_name as Customer";
        $group = "Customer";
    } elseif ($val = 6) {
        $field = "so.note as PO";
        $group = "PO";
    } elseif ($val = 7) {
        $field = "so.state as Status";
        $group = "Status";
    } elseif ($val = 8) {
        $field = "COALESCE(del.state, 'Waiting Availability') del_status";
        $group = "del_status";
    }
    echo "$field";
    echo "$val";
    $result = pg_query("

                    SELECT      ".$field."


                FROM sale_order so

                INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol
                    ON so.id = sol.order_id
                INNER JOIN res_partner as c
                    ON so.partner_id = c.id
                LEFT JOIN account_payment_term as ap
                    ON so.payment_term_id = ap.id
                INNER JOIN product_uom as pu
                    ON sol.product_uom = pu.id
                LEFT JOIN account_tax_sale_order_line_rel as acs
                    ON sol.id = acs.sale_order_line_id
                LEFT JOIN account_tax as at
                    ON acs.account_tax_id = at.id
                INNER JOIN product_template as pt
                    ON sol.product_id = pt.id
                LEFT JOIN mrp_bom as bom
                    ON pt.id = bom.product_tmpl_id
                LEFT JOIN mrp_bom_line as boml
                    ON bom.id = boml.bom_id
                INNER JOIN res_users as u
                    On so.create_uid = u.id

                Left    Join (Select sp1.id, sp1.origin, sp1.state, spo1.qty_done, spo1.product_id, spo1.picking_id, sp1.date_done
                                From stock_picking as sp1
                                Full    Join stock_pack_operation as spo1
                                On          sp1.id = spo1.picking_id) as del
                On      so.name = del.origin
                And     sol.product_id = del.product_id

                GROUP BY ".$group."

            ");
    while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't bother the queries just the GET VALUE is what i need to resolve. TIA All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, "=" is an assignment rather than a comparison operator ("==" or "===" for its type sensitive sibling).

So as soon as your first `if` is called, your actual value is overwritten.

You might also consider PHP's [`switch ... case`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) structure which is designed for such situations and still plays nicely with string data.

Try:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table class="table">
<?php
    include('../includes/links/js.php');
    include('../includes/links/css.php');
    include('/connection/connect.php');
    $val = intval($_GET['q']);
    $field = '';
    $group = '';

    if ($val == 1) {
        $field = "(SELECT pp1.name_template FROM product_product pp1 WHERE boml.product_id = pp1.id) as BOML";
        $group = "BOML";
    } elseif ($val == 2) {
        $field = "so.name as SO";
        $group = "SO";
    } elseif ($val == 3) {
        $field = "sol.name as assembly";
        $group = "assembly";
    } elseif ($val == 4) {
        $field = "split_part(u.login, '@', 1) as sales_person";
        $group = "sales_person";
    } elseif ($val == 5) {
        $field = "c.display_name as Customer";
        $group = "Customer";
    } elseif ($val == 6) {
        $field = "so.note as PO";
        $group = "PO";
    } elseif ($val == 7) {
        $field = "so.state as Status";
        $group = "Status";
    } elseif ($val == 8) {
        $field = "COALESCE(del.state, 'Waiting Availability') del_status";
        $group = "del_status";
    }
    echo "$field";
    echo "$val";
    $result = pg_query("

                    SELECT      ".$field."


                FROM sale_order so

                INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol
                    ON so.id = sol.order_id
                INNER JOIN res_partner as c
                    ON so.partner_id = c.id
                LEFT JOIN account_payment_term as ap
                    ON so.payment_term_id = ap.id
                INNER JOIN product_uom as pu
                    ON sol.product_uom = pu.id
                LEFT JOIN account_tax_sale_order_line_rel as acs
                    ON sol.id = acs.sale_order_line_id
                LEFT JOIN account_tax as at
                    ON acs.account_tax_id = at.id
                INNER JOIN product_template as pt
                    ON sol.product_id = pt.id
                LEFT JOIN mrp_bom as bom
                    ON pt.id = bom.product_tmpl_id
                LEFT JOIN mrp_bom_line as boml
                    ON bom.id = boml.bom_id
                INNER JOIN res_users as u
                    On so.create_uid = u.id

                Left    Join (Select sp1.id, sp1.origin, sp1.state, spo1.qty_done, spo1.product_id, spo1.picking_id, sp1.date_done
                                From stock_picking as sp1
                                Full    Join stock_pack_operation as spo1
                                On          sp1.id = spo1.picking_id) as del
                On      so.name = del.origin
                And     sol.product_id = del.product_id

                GROUP BY ".$group."

            ");
    while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OMG. Yeah i forgot that. I've been coding for a quite time but i forgot that PHP is like that. Guess its hard to switch PLs. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I know the feeling only too well! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Cheers!